# How to remove a seized bottom bracket from a titanium frame?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I can't loosen it even with a long breaker bar.

Comment: Make sure you're turning it the right direction.

Comment: Add easing or penetrating oil periodically for a while, so it soaks in through the threads.   Confirm the thread directions, and try both tightening and loosening it to break any seal first.
Last resort would be to cut it out, but the risk of thread damage is huge.

Comment: What is the BB made of? First rule out galvanic corrosion, because that can weld the two parts together and require destructive removal.

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely positive you know the direction of the threads, then an air operated impact wrench will do wonders.  I'm amazed at the difference when I remove threaded rear cassettes from my single speed wheels.  Removal by hand requires a long breaker bar, and a second person to hold the wheel from spinning.  Impact wrench is brizzzppp and done.  Its much easier to hold the tools tight to the work piece this way.  With long breaker bar, that's not so easy.

Again you need to know which direction is which.  (thumbs up to Daniel R. Hicks)

Comment: You will also have to absolutely place it in a solid stand that is mounted to the floor (not a folding stand). Getting seized parts out of titanium requires a LOT of force; make sure you clamp the frame as close as possible to the bottom bracket to reduce frame deflection. Also be sure to use plenty of fresh anti-seize when you put a new bottom bracket in.

Comment: Also, the fit between your removal tool and the BB has to be VERY secure. Make sure it's a good fit!